# zeppelin-python test failure

Tags: maven-3, apache-zeppelin

now i set up zeppelin in my local pc...
i want to know about zeppelin source code

but i'm in trouble..

At first, i get the source code on pc using get.
an then build

```
mvn instll
```

it has errors

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 25:06 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-30T17:22:21+09:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 174M/1182M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project zeppelin-python: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/##pcname##/Documents/zeppelin/zeppelin-master/python/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :zeppelin-python
```

Comment: python test require some python packages installed. https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/testing/install_external_dependencies.sh

Comment: @zjffdu  already install library in my local pc...
 but  retry mvn install in zepelin-master folder, errors..
TESTS org.apache.zeppelin.python.IPythonInterpreterTest 

 ({main} IPythonInterpreter.java[launchIPythonKernel]:300) - Wait for IPython Kernel to be started